# My external IDE Hard Drive is not getting detected in Windows 7 and 10... rest other drives are working in same machines

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, windows-10

Device USB\VID_13FD&PID_1040\0000000000000000W could not be migrated.

- Last Device Instance Id: USB\VID_0BB4&PID_05F0&MI_01\7&2A4EAB36&0&0001
- Class Guid: {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}
- Location Path:
- Migration Rank: 0xF000FFFF0000F130
- Present: false
- Status: 0xC0000719

Comment: Perhaps the drive or its external caddy is just dead. Try the problematic drive on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the message you specified, it appears you have a USB to IDE connector. You might have Device blocking happening. Try to remove ghost device from your machine. Unplug device from your machine first.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/504/how-to-uninstall-hidden-devices-drivers-and-services/

Follow the instruction in the link afterwards reboot and re-plug your device into your machine.

Best of Luck.